# android View reset setNextFocusUpId to default behaviour

Tags: android

I'm implementing this to android tv box with remote functionality.

I have a LinearLayout in ScrollView containing generated View.

I'm programmatically set the NextFocusUpId for the first View to the last View and vice versa so when user navigate up through the first View, it's rotate to the last View and vice versa.

the problem is when i sort the list with alphabetical order later, the first and last View got place in the middle, and when user navigate up through the list and arrive at the first View (before the sort), it's jump to the last View (before the sort), instead of the View next up to it.

if I set the NextFocusUpId to itself, user cannot navigate through the View before and after the sort of the View.

```
view1.setNextFocusUpId(view1.getId());
```

if possible I'd like to avoid to manually iterate the views and add the NextFocusUpId and NextFocusDownId in each view when the sorting is being run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this question being made, I found this solution.

```
view1.setNextFocusUpId(View.NO_ID);
```

do the reset.

EDIT:
It appear that in the documentation, there is the solution in the documentation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setNextFocusDownId%28int%29

```
Parameters
nextFocusDownId     The next focus ID, or NO_ID if the framework should decide automatically.
```